# Can I programming Bluetooth module internal registers through UART?

Tags: embedded, bluetooth

I have a customized [Amicomm A8107](http://amiccom.weebly.com/uploads/3/9/5/9/3959395/a8107_datasheet_v0_1(objective).pdf) Bluetooth System-in-package (SiP) module for a project in a PCB with a [STM32F103Z micro-controller](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00191185.pdf). I have 5 connections between my microcontroller and the BT module:

1. RF_RST#
2. WAKEUP
3. UART_RX
4. UART_TX
5. RF_INT

There are 4 further connections between the BT SiP and a 5 pin external interface to the board (which I assume are the JTAG pins?). The in BT SiP datasheet the 4 pins are labelled as:

1. RF module supply voltage
2. GPIO/ICE
3. TTAG_TTDIO/PWM2
4. TTAG_TTCK/PWM3

A company designed a UART interface of BT SiP for the project; I am not at liberty to disclose the details of that interface. But I looked through it and I could not find any UART commands to either program the BT module registers or to shut it down. The intended design was to control the BT module with the `RF_RST#` and the `WAKEUP` pins. Setting `RF_RST#` (which is connected to pin PA12 in our micro-controller) LOW should put the BT in sleep mode; but we are using the [stm32duino](https://github.com/stm32duino) backend for our firmware. The backend reserves the PA12 pin high and prevents the firmware from controlling it. We think it is caused by having the `-DSERIAL_USB` in the build configuration for our microcontroller as described [here](http://stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?t=1998).

One of my ideas is to turn it off by programming the relevant register in the module (9.2.2 in the [datasheet](http://amiccom.weebly.com/uploads/3/9/5/9/3959395/a8107_datasheet_v0_1(objective).pdf)). I have a manual for the module which I used to find the address of the register which I need to program. However, my interface to the module is restricted: I can only access it using UART.

I want to know the following things:

1. Do you guys it maybe possible to program the register through the UART?
2. Might it be possible to program the registers through the connections of the module to the external interface pins?

*EDIT:* Added model of bluetooth and some other details about my hardware platform

Comment: Virtually any general-purpose BT module with serial interface is allowing (and *requiring*) it for the module configuration. Of course only the parameters which are required for configuration and not some random internal registers of the underlying controllers.

Comment: This question is not appropriate here.  You understand that this would depend on the specific model, and then ignore that and ask a general question without specifying the model of interest.  Neither open-ended questions nor part search questions nor "are there any __" questions fit within the mission of stack exchange sites such as this.  All that can really be said is that this is *only* possible where there is firmware on the module which interprets serial commands and takes the action you desire as a result, or which permits you to load new software via serial, which you know how to write.

Comment: Share the make & model of the Bluetooth module. Please describe what exactly are your needs. Most of the "easy" modules support AT commands to change PIN, visibility, power etc. Some modules have an accessible MCU inside (eg. Nordic, TI) and you can make your own custom firmware..

Comment: You'll find it a lot easier to fix the STM32 code and/or move the signal to a different pin.  Also, you probably don't want to be using stm32duino in what sounds like a closed source commercial product anyway.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for your inputs. We cannot move the pins now; we are too far into development. Your advice about stm32duino is noted :)